# Upgrade python 2 to 3 and django 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have developed a django-rest api project in python 2.7 and django 1.6 now I want to upgrade it in python 3.4 and django 1.7.

I want to know the best way to port my code and also what consequences may occur on porting my code.

Comment: one of the best way is using `unittest`. checking your test files in new version of django

Comment: Django 1.7 hasn't even been released yet. Try to do one upgrade at a time, instead of both at once. For example get your project working with Python 3 and Django 1.6, then upgrade Django later.

Comment: pip install PIL in python 3.2 virtualenv showing error....

" File "/home/usr/work/fsop3.3/build/PIL/setup.py", line 182 print "--- using Tcl/Tk libraries at", TCL_ROOT ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Answer (score 1):

Like the comment says, use unit tests and make sure every single line of your code is hit by your tests. A lot of the module names have changed/were moved or combined with other modules. Every time your unit test says it cant find a certain module or method you can use this guide to figure out how to rename your imports/function calls. 
http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html

Comment: Integration tests are better for full code coverage. You can't unit test 3rd party libraries and how your app interacts with them. (Well, not very effectively, anyway.)

Comment: thanks.... but i am trying to install PIL(pip install PIL) in my virtualenv(python3.2) and its showing error....

"  File "/home/usr/work/fsop3.3/build/PIL/setup.py", line 182
    print "--- using Tcl/Tk libraries at", TCL_ROOT
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

how to resolve it?

Comment: PIL is not python 3 compatible as far as i know. Use pillow. Its djangos preferred imaging library anyway.